# Pandas is not showing data in descending order

Tags: python, pandas

I was arranging ep_next data in descending order and found that 14.1 appears far later, even though it is the highest number. This was the code I wrote for that:

```
import pandas as pd

import json

import requests

scrape_url = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/"

r= requests.get(scrape_url).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(r["elements"])

a = df[["first_name", "second_name", "news", "selected_by_percent", "points_per_game", "influence_rank", "chance_of_playing_next_round", "form", "ep_next"]]

b = a[a.news == ""].sort_values(by=["ep_next"], ascending = False )

b
```

Comment: Please edit your question - add definition of df.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(r['elements'])`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure df["ep_next"] is float. If not, convert the column to `float`, then sorting would work as expected:

```
df["ep_next"]=df["ep_next"].astype(float)
```

Comment: Hey, I am new to Python. It did work now but I want to know why it didn't earlier, because a float number was only at the top